# How do I get Lando to compile the SASS to CSS when I save the SASS file on Windows 10?

Tags: css, windows, sass, lando

I am using Lando to spin up an instance of a WordPress site on a Windows 10 machine.  My Mac counterparts tell me that, when they save a a change to a SASS file, Lando (using Gulp) automatically compiles the SASS to the necessary CSS.  This doesn't happen for me.

I have tried running Lando on Windows, as well as Ubuntu through WSL2 and still the CSS does not get automatically compiled.  I can run a `lando dev` to get the CSS to compile, but that takes a couple of minutes to complete.

I really have no idea why the Macs are auto-compiling and Windows (and Ubuntu in WSL2) are not compiling.

Here is my terminal when I set webpack to watch for changes:

[image]

I have spent days trying to solve this issue, but to no avail.  Any help is vastly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Christopher, any error messages you're seeing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AkinHwan Not that I can tell, but I have added a screenshot to the original posting so you can see what the terminal gives me when it's supposed to be watching for changes.

Comment: Are you using gulpjs or some other tool to handle your SASS etc.?